# Loading layout in onCreateView for custom preference

Tags: android, layout, preferences

Can I load layout from xml during onCreateView call, I tried:

- setLayoutResource(R.layout.test);
- setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.test);

it crashes and I don’t know what to return a ViewGroup parent from a method arguments?
I also tried:

- View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.test, parent) but it didn’t worked as well.

I named root layout widget_frame but it didn’t helped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:padding="1dp" android:clickable="false" android:id="@+id/widget_frame">
 <LinearLayout ....
```

Could you tell me what I’m doing wrong or point me to some working example.
Thanks

**Update**

Below is a woking solution on how to inflate above layout:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater)getContext().
                              getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
```

Comment: Great! this worked for me too! But the documentation was a little confusing as it said: 

"The default behavior is to inflate the main layout of this Preference (see setLayoutResource(int)." I just did not get what the purpose of calling setLayoutResource could be, as we clearly need to return a View and setLayoutResource returns void.

Comment: If you want to set the layout with `setLayoutResource` your view's id should be `"@android:id/widget_frame"` not `"@+id/widget_frame"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `onCreateView` I guess you are either using a `fragment` or extending a `View`.
Anyway check this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inflating a layout you should do something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
}
```